# Play framework vs. logic on client side

Tags: playframework

I have been "playing" with the Play framework and I can see that when building web pages logic resides at the server side (for example, when processing variables). This seems to go against having logic at the client side with frameworks such as Angular or Knockout. Am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This seems to go against having logic at the client side with frameworks such as Angular or Knockout.

You are right. But **going against** is not to be understood in a negative way!

AngularJS, Knockout and similar are client-side framework. Being that, it is only natural that also the logic is handled there (on the client-side).

Play Framework is a full-stack web framework - meaning it covers every aspect - from your database, through your business logic, to the presentation layer. And Play Framework is also more of a server-side framework - so this is why you will find the logic in the controllers (or services, or similar). The controllers reside where the application is deployed and this is the server. So there you have your server-side approach.

Being a full-stack web framework, Play allows you to build a whole application using (almost) only its features. But you are of course free to mix everything. You can use Play Framework for providing a solid backend, expose a nice REST API and let your AngularJS-based single page app communicate and present the data.